# Localization Problem in Objective C

Tags: iphone

I want to detect the “automatic” language from the device .Basically , I want device language from settings programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer myself.

whenever I have to use particular language I used

NSArray *lang = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lang forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

& whenever I want to use  device language from settings I used

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];

It really worked.

Answer (score 0):

To get the current locale, use the [`NSLocale`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class:

```
NSLocale *currentLocale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
NSLog(@"Locale: %@", [currentLocale localeIdentifier]);
```

Comment: Basically, my app shows option to switch between various languages, so what I am doing is                                              [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:lang forKey:@"AppleLanguages"]; where lang for example is lang = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"it", nil];

Comment: I also have an option"auto" which is suppose to detect device current language.I tried your code Alex, but it doesnot works for me.Even when app is switched to spanish , I get Locale: en_US